# Has anyone ever heard of an op amp oscillating after it saturates?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillation

I have an OPA690 that works fine during normal operation, but weird things happen when it saturates.

After hitting the negative power rail (-5V), the amplifier produces a damped sine response (sine * negative exponential). It is a very small signal (mV) that takes lots of averaging to be able to see. It also takes a very long time to fade (milliseconds). The amplifier is setup to have a bandwidth of a few hundred MHz, so it is surprising to see something last milliseconds.

I can't provide much more information. I am just wondering if anyone has heard of something like this before.

I will delete this question if it is too vague and I do not get any responses.

Thanks.

Comment: What frequency and what circuit is it used in?

Comment: If it's truly saturated it's likely not a small-signal oscillation due to the op-amp's feedback loop (since it's no longer closed).  Could it be that the load current is sinusoidal, and the r-on of the output stage is causing the voltage to move with load current?

Comment: The amplifier is in a complex system with hacks that try to boost the sample rate. The details make the measured frequency of the oscillation not totally useful. I was just wondering if anyone has ever seen any amplifier oscillate only after saturating.

Comment: What's providing power to the op-amp? Could the power supply voltage be oscillating in response to the step-like change in load current when you drive the op-amp into saturation?

Comment: @ThePhoton if the power supply was oscillating, that would be a result of the high frequency edge of the input signal right? The way I know the problem comes from my amplifier saturating, is it goes away once I put in clamping diodes. The diodes should preserve the high frequency components of the signal until they exceed the clamping voltage.

Comment: What is your load and circuit?

Comment: @DavidG25, it comes from the op-amp not decoupling the output from the power supply (no PSRR) when in saturation. (and the possibility that your power supply rings when load changes). Even if the input signal doesn't have a sharp edge, the transition from active to saturation could produce one in the power supply's load current. ...

Comment: I'm not clear where you installed clamping diodes, so I don't know what it means that the ring went away when you installed them. If the clamping diodes keep the op-amp from going into saturation, then it could also prevent the ring if my guess about root cause is correct.  A schematic (edited in to your question) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this in an op-amp designed to go to the rail. It oscillated continuously with a very small amplitude when the output was very near the negative rail (tens of mV). Probably the frequency compensation was ineffective in this range.

Quite a few years ago, so I don't remember the details, but I *think* it was an LMV324 type.

Ended up not using the part that behaved that way.

Answer (score 0):

If an opamp is not designed to go rail-to-rail then its response will become non-linear as the output voltage gets close to a rail. For example: if the output "drops" because it can no longer drive the low side output driver then this effectively increases your loop gain dramatically pushing you closer to instability.

You can add some type of limiting circuit:

1. Some kind of clamp on the input to limit the maximum input to the circuit.
2. Adding non-linear feedback that kicks in when output is too large, such as back-to-back zener diodes that bypass the feedback resistor. This reduces the opamp gain to unity when the zener voltage is hit.

Hope that helps, -Vince